# zend form validation returns false

Tags: forms, validation, zend-framework, return

I'm really confused with this one, really need your help. 
Here is the **AddsummonerForm.php**

```
<?php
class Form_AddsummonerForm extends Zend_Form{
    public function __construct($options = null){
        $this->setMethod('post')
             ->setAttrib('id','standard-form')
             ->setAction($options['action'])
             ->setEnctype(Zend_Form::ENCTYPE_MULTIPART);
        $user = Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity();

        $name = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('name');
        $name->setAttribs(array(
                                'placeholder' => "Enter the Summoner's name")
                                )
                 ->setRequired()
                 ->addErrorMessage("Please check the name.")
                 ->addValidator('StringLength',false,array(4,15))
                 ->addValidator('Alnum')
                 ->removeDecorator('label')
                 ->removeDecorator('Errors')
                 ->removeDecorator('htmlTag')
                 ->removeDecorator('DtDdWrapper');

        $regions = array("euw" => "EUW", 
                        "eune" => "EUNE", 
                        "na"=>"NA", 
                        "brazil" => "Brazil", 
                        "turkey" => "Turkey");

        $region = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('region');
        $region->addMultiOptions($regions)
                ->addErrorMessage('Please check the region.')
                ->removeDecorator('label')
                ->removeDecorator('Errors')
                ->removeDecorator('htmlTag')
                ->removeDecorator('DtDdWrapper');

        $validate = new Zend_Form_Element_File('validate');
        $validate->setDestination(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../public/images/users/'.$user->getId())
        ->addValidator('Count', false, 1)
        ->addValidator('Extension',false,'jpg,gif,png')
        ->addValidator('Size',false,1024000)
        ->addErrorMessage('Please check the file.')
        ->removeDecorator('label')
        ->removeDecorator('Errors')
        ->removeDecorator('htmlTag')
        ->removeDecorator('DtDdWrapper');

        $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit');
        $submit->setLabel('Add')
               ->removeDecorator('DtDdWrapper');

        $this->setDecorators(array(
                                array(
                                    'ViewScript', array(
                                            'viewScript' => '_form_add_summoner.phtml'
                                            )
                                    )
                                )
                            );

        $this->addElements(array($name, $region, $validate, $submit));
    }
    }
```

which is a pretty common form, then the controller SummonerController with the action add, which is:

```
        $errors = array();
    $addForm = new Form_AddsummonerForm(array(
            'action'=> '/summoner/add')
    );

    if($this->getRequest()->isPost()){
        if($addForm->isValid($this->_request->getPost())){

            // .... code ....

        }else{
            $errorArray = $addForm->getErrors();
            foreach($errorArray as $error){
                $errors[] = $error;
            }
            $this->view->errors = $errors;
        }
    }
    $this->view->form = $addForm;
```

Thing is, that when i submit the form the $addForm->isValid($this->_request->getPost())) returns false.

I tried dumping the $addForm->getMessages,$addForm->getErrors and they are empty, however it still returns false!
Any ideas?

Comment: have you tested it with both valid/invalid data? what are the results?

Comment: is it possible that your php.ini setting `post_max_size` is lower than the file you are trying to upload?

Comment: @farzad tried it out with valid data, it retuns false and the form->getMessages/Errors don't return anything, with invalid data it still returns false, but the getErrors returns the associated error.

Comment: @moeso nah, I checked it again but it doesn't seem to be the problem

Comment: Have you checked the html MAX_FILE_SIZE parameter in your form? Make sure it is greater or equal to 1024000. Also, you should not remove the Error decorators while testing, so that you can see them. Also try dumping posted values to make sure they're all sent properly, right before validating the form: echo '<pre>',print_r($this->_request->getPost()),'</pre>';